# Debugging in CLion on an M1 Macbook Pro

Tags: c++, debugging, intel, clion, apple-m1

Code builds and runs perfectly, but I cannot debug my code. I am an M1 Macbook Pro user and I think the issue lies there. The architecture of Clion as shown in the activity monitor is Intel.
The code exits with code 139- interrupted by signal 11- SIGSEGV- segmentation fault.

[error message after attempting to debug the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tws0J.png)

[intel architecture of Clion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic3VP.jpg)

code

```
// Created by Kashita Talreja on 22/12/20.
//
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


bool isvalid(int n) {
    int tmp = n;
    while(tmp) {
        int x = (tmp % 10);
        if(x > 0 && n % x >  0) return false;
        tmp /= 10;
    }
    return true;
}

void solve() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int ok = 0;
    while(!isvalid(n)) {
        n++;
    }
    cout << n << endl;

}
int32_t main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        solve();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem on a M1 Mac mini. I don't think this is a code problem: I can't even reach a breakpoint in the first line of the main function. You probably had the correct intuition with the architecture difference... no clue how to solve it though.

Comment: I'm afraid we are out of luck... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-23065?_ga=2.102972736.1193501900.1608635331-738132866.1608536763

Comment: I've switched to XCode, it's a pretty good replacement for now :)